# Iterate 2D array in angular js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have following array declared in my js file

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.tempArr = [
      ["block A1", "block B1", "block C1"],
      ["block A2", "block B2", "block C2"]
    ];
}
```

And now in angular i want to iterate over this array and print result like

```
block A1 block B1 block C1
block A2 block B2 block C2
```

I used to print using :

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <div>
  <div ng-repeat="row in tempArr">
      <input type="text" value="{{row[$index]}}">
      <input type="text" value="{{row[$index+1]}}">
      <input type="text" value="{{row[$index+2]}}">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't print block A2. How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: <div ng-repeat="row in tempArr">
                            <div ng-repeat ="col in row track by $index">
                                <input type="text" value="{{col}}">
                            </div>
                        </div>

That's how it should be

Answer (score 2):

nest your `ng-repeat`s like so

```
<div ng-repeat="row in data">
    <div ng-repeat="col in row">
        // do stuff here
    </div>
</div>
```

or you can flatten you 2d array to one new array and use one `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 1):

Get the nested ng-repeats to deep-traverse your arrays like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in tempArr">
    <div ng-repeat="col in row">
        <input type="text" value="{{col}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the last post. This is absolutely perfect.